# Compute the number of unfinished events with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 3 events timestamps: e0, e1 and e2. Other columns are the row id and a target variable.

For illustration, let's say this is a e-commerce section dataset and

- e0: time user opens the website
- e1: time user selects the item
- e2: time user buys item

I would like to count (or compute other statistics) for each user, how many users are in between events 1 and 2 currently.

I have managed to do it using `pandasql`, but not with native pandas functions:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from pandasql import sqldf

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 5: 5, 4: 4, 6: 6, 7: 7},
 'e0': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:10:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:11:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:20:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:20:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:24:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:50:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:55:00')},
 'e1': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:20:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:55:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:31:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:40:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:50:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:54:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-01-01 13:03:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-01-01 13:00:00')},
 'e2': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:25:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 13:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:36:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:56:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-01-01 13:30:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 12:58:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-01-01 13:50:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-01-01 13:20:00')},
 'target': {0: '100',
  1: '120',
  2: '110',
  3: '105',
  5: '120',
  4: '140',
  6: '130',
  7: '200'}})


sqldf("""
SELECT df1.id, COUNT(df2.id)
FROM df df1
JOIN df df2 ON df1.e0 > df2.e1 AND df1.e0 < df2.e2
GROUP BY df1.id

""")
```

or, like I said, to compute statistics:

```
sqldf("""

SELECT df1.id, AVG(df2.target)
FROM df df1
JOIN df df2 ON df1.e0 > df2.e1 AND df1.e0 < df2.e2
GROUP BY df1.id
""")
```

Comment: There's not enough info. We don't clearly know what a user who is between events 1 and 2 looks like. There's no desired output.

Comment: Hey, the desired output is exacly like foglerit presented

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same results in your queries with a `df.merge` and a `query` operation as a filter.

For your first query:

```py
res1 = df.assign(key=1).merge(
    df.assign(key=1),
    on="key",
    suffixes=["", "_2"]
).query(
    "e0 > e1_2 & e0 < e2_2"
).groupby("id").id_2.count()
print(res1)

id
4    1
6    1
7    3
Name: id_2, dtype: int64
```

For your second query:

```py
df["target"] = df.target.astype(int)
res2 = df.assign(key=1).merge(
    df.assign(key=1),
    on="key",
    suffixes=["", "_2"]
).query(
    "e0 > e1_2 & e0 < e2_2"
).groupby("id").target_2.mean()
print(res2)

id
4    100.000000
6    105.000000
7    121.666667
Name: target_2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for the toy example, but as the data frame grows it explodes. I was looking for a solution that has a similar performance